# What is the equivalent of boost::system::error_code with GetLastError in C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

In my application, we're trying to remove boost features and replace with C++ Standard Library features. Here I've a boost::system::error_code prepared from GetLastError and thrown from one place. And handled in another place by preparing error string.

```
void fun()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec(GetLastError(), boost::system::system_category()); 
    throw ec;
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        fun();
    }
    catch ( boost::system::error_code ec )
    {
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
          string strError(ec.message();
    }
}
```

I found that I can replace it with std::error_code. But when I try with a sample program, I'm not able to get the same string. I tried all three categories of std::error_code. I need a replacement, which gives exact same string.

```
//Returns the last Win32 error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size - 3);  // Getting rid of trailing characters: ".\r\n"

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    SetLastError(ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED);

    std::error_code er(GetLastError(), std::generic_category());
    cout << "STD  Generic Error: " << er.message() << endl;

    std::error_code sysEr(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
    cout << "STD  System  Error: " << sysEr.message() << endl;

    std::error_code ioEr(GetLastError(), std::iostream_category());
    cout << "STD  I/O     Error: " << ioEr.message() << endl;

    cout << "STL          Error: " << GetLastErrorAsString() << endl;

    boost::system::error_code ec(GetLastError(), boost::system::system_category());
    cout << "Boost        Error: " << ec.message() << endl;
}
```

Output:

STD  Generic Error: unknown error

STD  System  Error: operation canceled

STD  I/O     Error: unknown error

STL          Error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Boost        Error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Comment: FYI: [There is no STL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5205571/2069064)

Comment: What is `GetLastErrorAsString()`?

Comment: @Barry, Thanks Barry. Modified the question accordingly

Comment: You need a fairy godmother that calls FormatMessage() to convert the error number to a string.  Like boost does.  You will not get that out of the std namespace, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the fairy god mother herself. Added now. Please check!!!